# Spring auto configuration doesn't find generic classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.5 and I'm trying to implement an auto-configuration class (called `OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration`) for one of my open-source projects. In this project, I have a generic interface defined like this:

```
public interface CloudEventConverter<T> {
        ... 
}
```

I'd like the auto-configuration to create a default bean of such as interface, unless it already exists. Here's the code that I have in my auto-configuration class:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventTypeMapper.class)
public CloudEventTypeMapper<?> occurrentTypeMapper() {
    return ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.qualified();
}
```

Now, this `CloudEventTypeMapper` is used in this method:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventConverter.class)
public <T> CloudEventConverter<?> occurrentCloudEventConverter(Optional<ObjectMapper> objectMapper, OccurrentProperties occurrentProperties, CloudEventTypeMapper<T> cloudEventTypeMapper) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper.orElseGet(ObjectMapper::new);
    return new JacksonCloudEventConverter.Builder<T>(mapper, occurrentProperties.getCloudEventConverter().getCloudEventSource())
            .typeMapper(cloudEventTypeMapper)
            .build();
}
```

However, when I try to bootstrap an application that loads my auto-configuration, I get this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of method occurrentCloudEventConverter in org.occurrent.springboot.mongo.blocking.OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.occurrent.application.converter.typemapper.CloudEventTypeMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.occurrent.application.converter.typemapper.CloudEventTypeMapper' in your configuration.
```

This is even the case if I try to add such a bean manually:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun rpsTypeMapper(): CloudEventTypeMapper<GameEvent> = ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper. qualified(GameEvent::class.java)
```

If I debug the code, I can see that it goes into the `rpsTypeMapper`, but it doesn't seem to be injected to `occurrentCloudEventConverter` (and neither is the default `occurrentTypeMapper` bean).

I've tried removing the generics (`<T>`) in the `OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration` as well as replacing them with `<?>`, but it doesn't help.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

PS: Here's the code for the [OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/johanhaleby/occurrent/blob/decider-web/framework/spring-boot-starter-mongodb/src/main/java/org/occurrent/springboot/mongo/blocking/OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration.java), and here's the [bootstrap code](https://github.com/johanhaleby/occurrent/blob/decider-web/example/domain/rps/decider-model-web/src/main/kotlin/org/occurrent/example/domain/rps/decidermodel/web/Bootstrap.kt). It's also possible to start the app using test containers, by running [TestBootstrap](https://github.com/johanhaleby/occurrent/blob/decider-web/example/domain/rps/decider-model-web/src/test/kotlin/org/occurrent/example/domain/rps/decidermodel/TestBoostrap.kt).

To reproduce you can clone the repository from here: `git@github.com:johanhaleby/occurrent.git`, then switch branch to `decider-web` and run the main method in `org.occurrent.example.domain.rps.decidermodel.TestBoostrap`.

Comment: After running TestBootstrap class, Getting errors from `InMemoryEventStoreTest` and `CustomTypeMapperTest` classes.

Comment: I'm in the decider-web branch only.

Comment: Unable to run TestBootstrap code. Can you please help?

Comment: @AnishB. I just tried it again, and it works for me. I'm running it from Intellij.

Comment: Anything am I doing wrong? Suprising

Comment: When I'm running the main, why it's calling those two classes.

Comment: I can fix but I need the code running on my system :)

Comment: @AnishB. I'm sorry, but I don't know what's wrong. I just run the main method in "org.occurrent.example.domain.rps.decidermodel.TestBoostrap" from intellij and I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: No worries... I'm checking

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes up because Spring has a tough time figuring out the generic type for CloudEventTypeMapper.

To fix this, you can use a nifty class called ResolvableType from Spring:

```
public abstract class OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventTypeMapper.class)
    public CloudEventTypeMapper<?> occurrentTypeMapper() {
        return ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.qualified();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventConverter.class)
    public CloudEventConverter<?> occurrentCloudEventConverter(
            Optional<ObjectMapper> objectMapper,
            OccurrentProperties occurrentProperties,
            CloudEventTypeMapper<?> cloudEventTypeMapper) {
        
        ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(CloudEventConverter.class, cloudEventTypeMapper.getClass());

        ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper.orElseGet(ObjectMapper::new);
        return new JacksonCloudEventConverter.Builder<>(mapper, occurrentProperties.getCloudEventConverter().getCloudEventSource())
                .typeMapper((CloudEventTypeMapper) resolvableType.resolveGeneric())
                .build();
    }
}
```

With this change, Spring should now be able to figure out the generic type for CloudEventTypeMapper and create the occurrentCloudEventConverter bean smoothly.
Give it a try and see if it solves your issue!

Comment: It still doesn't work, I get the same error:

Parameter 2 of method occurrentCloudEventConverter in org.occurrent.springboot.mongo.blocking.OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.occurrent.application.converter.typemapper.CloudEventTypeMapper' that could not be found.

I think it happens _before_ the occurrentCloudEventConverter is even called, it's like it's not finding the CloudEventTypeMapper<?> instance.

Comment: If you have multiple auto-configuration classes, ensure that the order of their execution is appropriate. You can set the order explicitly using the @AutoConfigureOrder annotation, or Explicitly Declare the Bean in a Configuration Class

Comment: I don't have multiple auto-configuration classes, I only have the one mentioned above (see code).

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code for testing:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventConverter.class)
public <T> CloudEventConverter<?> occurrentCloudEventConverter(Optional<ObjectMapper> objectMapper, OccurrentProperties occurrentProperties,
                                                               @Autowired(required = false) CloudEventTypeMapper<T> cloudEventTypeMapper) {
    cloudEventTypeMapper = ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.qualified();
    ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapper.orElseGet(ObjectMapper::new);
    return new JacksonCloudEventConverter.Builder<T>(mapper, occurrentProperties.getCloudEventConverter().getCloudEventSource())
            .typeMapper(cloudEventTypeMapper)
            .build();
}
```

Prompt following questions:

```
  OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration#occurrentTypeMapper:
  Did not match:
     - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.occurrent.application.converter.typemapper.CloudEventTypeMapper; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.occurrent.application.converter.typemapper.CloudEventTypeMapper' rpsTypeMapper (OnBeanCondition)
```

At Bootstrap.java, exists follow code:

```
@Bean
fun rpsTypeMapper(): CloudEventTypeMapper<GameEvent> = ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.simple(GameEvent::class.java)
```

caused occurrentTypeMapper in OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration.java not invoked:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventTypeMapper.class)
public CloudEventTypeMapper<?> occurrentTypeMapper() {
    return ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.qualified();
}
```

But the type `CloudEventTypeMapper<GameEvent>` not matched `occurrentCloudEventConverter`.

Otherwise remove `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(CloudEventTypeMapper.class)` will be ok.

```
@Bean
public CloudEventTypeMapper<?> occurrentTypeMapper() {
    return ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.qualified();
}
```

Comment: While I could remove the ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation, I want to create a default if the user has not specified one, regardless of generic type.

Comment: @Johan You need to remove  `fun rpsTypeMapper(): CloudEventTypeMapper<GameEvent> = ReflectionCloudEventTypeMapper.simple(GameEvent::class.java)
`. This will be the default one.